# Ubuntu 18.04 freezes when several applications are running, even keyboard is dead

Tags: keyboard

I'm running ubuntu 18.04 in an Aspire-M7811 desktop with a processor Intel® Core™ i5 CPU 650 @ 3.20GHz × 4. The case is that:when I open several aplications it freezes at all, even the keyboard is dead so I can only power down the pc.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the same question which is being asked before :
here is the link for the same,

[What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

maybe it will help you.

Comment: Thanks, I already tried all and  I reached the worst answer: When everything, keys and mouse and all, stop working:

First try the Magic SysReq method outlined in Phoenix' answer. If that doesn't work, press the Reset button on the computer case. If even that doesn't work, you'll just have to power-cycle the machine.
May you never reach this point. ( I reached it TT), thanks for your time!

Comment: did you tried: `ctrl`+`alt`+`f1`  and then logging in with user id and password and reset the GUI with the command:  `sudo service lightdm restart` actually it worked for me many times.

Comment: Yep, but the keyboard is dead : |

Comment: Keep `ctrl+alt+F1` pressed for some time, it will surely open a black terminal even though your keyboard is hanged. Worked for me always.